# How to get id of an Edge using igraph in python

Tags: python, igraph

I have an instance of the `Edge` class, but I can't find any attribute or method representing the id of that object. The weird thing is that I can see the id in the output of a `__str__` method:

```
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(2)
e = g.add_edge(0,1)
e.__str__()
```

Output:

`'igraph.Edge(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7fc00555e4f0>, 0, {})'`

0 - id of that edge

I can't use the `get_eid` method because it returns the id of only one edge but there may be multiple edges between vertices

Comment: What do you need ID's for? You could always store a dictionary of edges to id's if you needed.

Comment: There are about 500M vertices, I don't want to take up additional space for hash tables. Why it is so difficult to get the id from an edge?

Comment: this is the best I can see, if you have the 2 vertices the edges are between you can use `get_eids() `https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/api/igraph.GraphBase.html#get_eids

Comment: The problem of `get_eids()` is "The method does not consider multiple edges; if there are multiple edges between a pair of vertices, only the ID of one of the edges is returned."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `e` is an `Edge` object, you can get the corresponding edge ID as `e.index`.